# Angular Js: ng-repeat multiple filters error: Token 'track' is an unexpected token

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I want to filter a table by a date range. I have two input sections with their ng-model, one for the starting date - **filters.filterDataFrom**, and one for the ending date - **filters.filterDataTo**.

In my table I have **chained multiple filters together**, but when I try to chain the last one - **dateBefore**(function) - I get the following error:

Syntax Error: Token 'track' is an unexpected token at column 64 of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

I don't understand why, given that the same expression is used in the dateFilter function, and it works. The error comes only when I enter the last filter.

Here is the tr ng-repeat code:

```
<tr ng-model="tabel.reparatiiRepetate" ng-repeat="reparatieRepetata in tabel.reparatiiRepetate | filter: returnExpressionObject() | dateFilter: filters.filterDataFrom track by reparatieRepetata['data_1'] | dateBefore: filters.filterDataTo track by reparatieRepetata['data_1']">
```

Do you have any clue why this is happening?

Comment: You have two `track by` expressions. Remove the first one, since filters come before the `track by`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have found after a day of research that the regexp used in the ngRepeat directive, doesn't allow for pipes or other code after `track by`. It seems that some devs tried to modify it so that they could use at least plus two `track by`- [link](https://github.com/brianmarco/angular.js/commit/09eb6daa4e6f5ac41fa0688a9308994ae99a2c8c). Any way, I have resolved the issue by passing the parameters for the second filter (**datefilter**) using two colons - **:**, and I have used `track by` only for the last one. Thanks again! Best wishes!

Comment: Why do you need to use two `track by`s?

Comment: Cause I wanted to use them with the **two function filters** that filter the **date range**: one for **'after a selected date'**, the other for **'before a selected date'**.

Comment: That's the reason to use 2 filters; not 2 `track by`

Comment: Yep. And that's what I did :). And it worked!